# CoreBluetooth app does not find all Bluetooth devices - iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Is there a way to discover all Bluetooth devices in an iOS app? I am using CoreBluetooth and I get all iDevices around plus one unknown device. However if I go to General -> Bluetooth -> Devices it lists a couple of devices that are not listed by the example app I am making. I need to find a none Apple device in the list and connect to it. Is this possible? And how come the two lists (the system one and the one in the app) are different?

In case it is important it needs to be used for ODB2 system later on, but for now just listing the none Apple device in the discovered devices will do.

Here is the code I am using to list the devices:

```
class HRMViewController: UIViewController {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    }
}


extension HRMViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    switch central.state {
    case .unknown:
      print("central.state is .unknown")
    case .resetting:
      print("central.state is .resetting")
    case .unsupported:
      print("central.state is .unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
      print("central.state is .unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
      print("central.state is .poweredOff")
    case .poweredOn:
      print("central.state is .poweredOn")
      centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)

   }

  }

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    print(advertisementData)
    print(peripheral)

 }

}
```

Comment: You will only be able to discover BLE devices, not legacy devices such as hands free or headset devices

Comment: @Paulw11 What about devices that are not Apple devices - can I discover them?

Comment: As long as they are advertising BLE services

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you have an idea why in Settings are listed devices that are not listed in the app? Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: It depends on what is listed; you won’t discover handsfeee devices or cars or Apple Watch or any device that isn’t advertising a BLE service.

Comment: As said by @Paulw11, CoreBluetooth is only for Bluetooth Low-Energy, it's written in the introduction of the framework. BLE device don't need to be Made For iPhone. For the rest, you can't. Maybe with ExternalAccessory, but some device with legacy Bluetooth and some profile (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387) won't be seen there.